# join table and get data based on field value JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have two entities

```
 @Entity
    public class Module {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Integer id;
        private String name;
        private String descr;

        @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
        @JoinColumn(name="ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
        private List<Permissions> perms;

}

@Entity
public class Permissions {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private Integer clientId;
    private String role;
    private Character endorseCreate;
    private Character endorseUpdate;
    private Character endorseDelete;
    private Character endorseView;
```

I am trying to fetch data by first Module.name and Permissions.clientId and Permissions.role
Something like in sql

select * from Module m, Permissions p where m.id=p.id and p.clientId=1 and p.role='ADMIN'

How can I achieve using JPA, I am using spring data aswell.
Can a method be declared in CRUD Repo provided by spring data?

I think the issue is I am unable to find way to pass values to fetch data.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Please, read the relevant documentation and try something. This is too broad, and you absolutely must read the documentation for this fundamental stuff anyway. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query, https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql

Comment: @Query("select u from User u where u.emailAddress = ?1") All the examples are for Single entity, how can I pass in the second entity which is in onetomany relationship

Comment: That's not "all the example". That's the first example you found in the Spring Data JPA documentation. I gave you a link which points to the HQL/JPQL documentation, explaining basically everything you can do with JPQL, including joins. Read it. It takes more than 4 minutes.

Comment: Thank you, I think I should go for @filter, is there any other way?

Comment: No, you shouldn't. You need to write a query using a join, just like you're doing in SQL. Again, read the documentation about joins in JPQL.

Comment: I did this
@Query("select u, p from Module u, Permissions p where u.id = p.id and u.name=?1 and p.clientId=?2")
 Optional<Module> findByNameAndClientId(String targetType, Integer clientId);
I was thinking entity other than the type specified CrudRepository<Module, Integer> would only be accessible in @Query, It worked and thank you so much for that

Comment: It works, but that's not a proper way to do a join, and your mapping makes no sense: a Module is supposed to have several permissions, but you're using the ID of the permission, which is supposed to be unique, as the join column. So there's no way to have more than one permission for a given module. You need to rethink your design.

Comment: Yes now I have issue i was mapping to primary key and that is unique, anyhow i change JoinColumn to a foreign key @JoinColumn(name="MODULE_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"). Now how can I refer to module_id in @Query JPQL. That creates a column in Permissions table, but there is no field, if I declare moduleId in Permissions, it gives error at startup stateing duplicate columns defined [MODULE_ID][module_id] . Then how can I point to that module_id column field in JPQL, when it is not allowing me to declare that field in class?

Comment: This is the error Table [permissions] contains physical column name [module_id] referred to by multiple physical column names: [MODULE_ID], [moduleId]. I am trying to achieve OnetoMany unidirectional behaviour

Comment: Once again, you need to use a join, as described in the documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-explicit-join

Comment: can I achieve this by using filter which I was talking about. I think I have to try that, if you say if that is right way I will go for it, else I will go for explicit joins

Comment: I already answered that question. No. You need to use a join.